# Upgraded to 14.10 from 14.04 on Lenovo x201 dual-boot, freezes after login

Tags: upgrade, lenovo, freeze, 14.10

I upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 on my lenovo x201 laptop that is dual booted with windows and ubuntu using grub.

After I type in my password, the screen hangs and all i see is the background wallpaper.

I can boot in safe mode with failsafe graphics and it loads properly.

EDIT:

I was able to make it work by doing the following:

When the grub menu loads (you need to hold shift after the bios screen), I select my kernel image and press 'e' to edit the boot parameters. At the end of the line beginning with "Linux" I append the option "i915.modeset=0". Turns out I can omit the "xforcevesa" option.

Comment: you could try and install the latest intel drivers (i am assuming that your gpu is intel based) from here https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads (select the 14.04 one)

Comment: Did you try login as a guest or different user?

Answer (score 1):

When the grub menu loads (you need to hold shift after the bios screen), I select my kernel image and press 'e' to edit the boot parameters. At the end of the line beginning with "Linux" I append the option "i915.modeset=0". Turns out I can omit the "xforcevesa" option.